# how to add Apostrophe in php native

Tags: php

I have a following string

```
$data = "20150825131738_262,20150825132227_241,20150825132254_898,20150825132320_209";
```

How to  add `'` in `$data`. So the resultant output is as follows

```
'20150825131738_262','20150825132227_241','20150825132254_898','20150825132320_209,20150825132346_124','20150825132406_744','20150825143522_447','20150828145011_928'
```

help me thank's

Comment: Why don't you enclose your string while creating? Are you getting this string from somewhere else or what

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following would give you the desired results

```
$data = "20150825131738_262,20150825132227_241,20150825132254_898,20150825132320_209";
$data_array = explode(',', $data);
$data = "'". implode("','", $data_array) . "'";
print_r($data);
```

See it running online [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0862c070bb9a6907934469915c556adf15d436fd)

Answer (score 5):

Try This

```
$arr=explode(',', $data);

implode("','",$arr);
```

Comment: This'll generate `20150825131738_262','20150825132227_241','20150825132254_898','20150825132320_209`

Comment: yes this generate 
20150825131738_262','20150825132227_241','20150825132254_898','20150825132320_2‌​09

how to add ' in  front and rear

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting this value from database or some other sources then you can simply use one of these ways using simple `implode` and `explode` function as

```
$data = "20150825131738_262,20150825132227_241,20150825132254_898,20150825132320_209";
echo "'".implode("','",explode(',',$data))."'";
```

or using `preg_replace_callback` as

```
$data = "20150825131738_262,20150825132227_241,20150825132254_898,20150825132320_209";
echo preg_replace_callback('/[\d_]+/',function($match){ return "'$match[0]'";},$data);
```

Comment: Whats wrong with my answer and I think I've posted this answer earlier than Mubashar Ahmad

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = "20150825131738_262,20150825132227_241,20150825132254_898,20150825132320_209";
$pad_data = "'" . $data . "'"; 
$data = str_replace (",", "', '", $pad_data);
echo $data;
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different method from the other answers:

```
$data = '20150825131738_262,20150825132227_241,20150825132254_898,20150825132320_209';

# Split data into individual fields
$array = explode(',', $data);

# Surround each field with single quotes
$array = array_map(
    function ($field) { return "'${field}'"; },
    $array
);

# Join fields back into a single string again
$data = implode(',', $array);

echo $data;
```

The code can be seen running [here](http://ideone.com/Hy42cg).